# jQuery click.modalEvent

Tags: javascript, jquery

Revising code of jQuery.reveal plugin (http://www.zurb.com/playground/reveal-modal-plugin) and trying to understand how it handles the modal behaviour, I see that it binds the closeModal function (that closes the popup) to the event  `'click.modalEvent'`.

But I can't find any information about this event, I don't know if it belongs to javascript itself or if it's part of jQuery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the event type contains a period, it means it is namespaced and it will come in handy when you want to unbind the event. Without event namespaces, the only way to unbind a function is to unbind all events from the element, or to keep a reference to the function itself.

With namespaces, you can easily remove inline functions as well.

Assume we bind two events:

```
$('#element').bind('click.myEvents', function(){ /* inline function */ });
$('#element').bind('keypress.myEvents', function(){ /* inline function */ });
```

You can easily unbind the event using the namespace without having to create a named function:

```
$('#element').unbind('click.myEvents');
```

You can also unbind all events under the same namespace at once:

```
// This will get rid of both the click and keypress handlers.
$('#element').unbind('.myEvents');
```

For more information, see the [jQuery documentation page](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) for `unbind()`.

Comment: wow, I though it was a special event or something... never end learning new things about javascript/jquery

Answer (score 0):

it's probably custom event.
See [this](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/03/09/custom-events-in-javascript/) post.

Comment: probably, but I can't see where jquery.reveal defines it then... the only references to modalEvent are related to jquery.bind() and jquery.unbind() calls.